# Neo4j: iterate over node ids and call a procedure

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way with Neo4j (3.0.1) to iter over all nodes ids for a specific label and apply a procedure to each of those ids?

At the moment I am doing something like:

```
MATCH (p:Person) CALL example.myprocedure(ID(p)) RETURN p
```

but I don't want to return anything. `MATCH` forces me to return a value.

The eventual iteration can be parallelized too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[neo4j-apoc-procedures](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) has a procedure called `rock_n_roll` allowing you to iterate over something and then perform an action in with configurable transaction batch size on it. I guess that's pretty close to what you're looking for.

Example:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll(
   'MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p', // what we iterate over
   'WITH {p} as p SET p.lastname = p.name', // action to take for each iteration
   5000 // tx batch size
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use apoc procedure as action to do for each iteration?